# Exit tcsh script if error

Tags: shell, tcsh

I am tryin to write a tcsh script. 
I need the script exit if any of its commands fails.

In shell I use `set -e` but I don't know its equivalent in tcsh

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh

set NAME=aaaa
set VERSION=6.1

#set -e equivalent
#do somthing
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? Else did you check `man tcsh`? Good luck.

Comment: When I use set -e as in shell, I got this error: set: Variable name must begin with a letter.

Comment: Looking at the man page, I think you have to use it like `#!/bin/tcsh -e ...` (at the top of the file, of course). Good luck.

Comment: When I put `#!/bin/tcsh -e` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env tcsh`, the script does no thing. tcsh commands are not executed

Comment: ok, apparently I didn't guess the correct path where `tcsh` lives.If `#!/usr/bin/env tcsh -e` doesn't work, then find the correct path to `tcsh` and edit the she-bang as needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In (t)csh, `set` is used to define a variable; `set foo = bar` will assign the value `bar` to the variable `foo` (like `foo=bar` does in Bourne shell scripting).

In any case, from `tcsh(1)`:

```
Argument list processing
   If the first argument (argument 0) to the shell is `-'  then  it  is  a
   login shell.  A login shell can be also specified by invoking the shell
   with the -l flag as the only argument.

   The rest of the flag arguments are interpreted as follows:

[...]

   -e  The  shell  exits  if  any invoked command terminates abnormally or
       yields a non-zero exit status.
```

So you need to invoke `tcsh` with the `-e` flag. Let's test it:

```
% cat test.csh
true
false

echo ":-)"

% tcsh test.csh
:-)

% tcsh -e test.csh
Exit 1
```

There is no way to set this at runtime, like with `sh`'s `set -e`, but you can add it to the hashbang:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -fe
false
```

so it gets added automatically when you run `./test.csh`, but this will **not** add it when you type `csh test.csh`, so my recommendation is to use something like a `start.sh` which will invoke the `csh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
tcsh -ef realscript.csh
```

Comment: You've also set the `-f`-flag here – what does that flag do?

Comment: From tcsh man page ...
       -f  The shell does not load any resource or startup files, or perform any command hashing, and thus starts faster.